# When does the Yom Kippur fast actually start?

Tags: yom-kippur, candle-lighting

Does the fast start after candle lighting (i.e., 18 mins before sunset) or does it start strictly at sunset?

I suppose that if it starts immediately after candle lighting, one can light candles closer to sunset to start it as late as possible.

Comment: Thank you, that other question has the answer I was looking for.